# Angular 6 components

Tags: javascript, angular

I have around 100 screens in my application and out of which 25 are search screens. Each search screen has multiple things in common.

For instance:

```
Screen #1:
**Label**           **Input type**
First name:         Textbox
Date:               Date picker
Some other text boxes or radio buttons
```

```
Screen #2:  
**Label**           **Input type**  
Other name:         Textbox  
Date:               Date picker  
Some other text boxes or radio buttons
```

Basically, I am moving my servlet/jsp application to Angular 6. I re-searched today how I can declare components and re-use them. I haven't yet fully understood angular 6 syntax and structure and I am learning as we speak.

What I currently have in mind is:

In my `@Component`, i can have something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom_elem',
  template: `
Generate html as per parameters provided by user
  `
export class SubscriberComponent implements OnInit {  
  @Input() parameters;
}
```

And I pass parameters like this for `Screen #1`:

```
<custom_elem [parameters]="['First Name', 'textbox', 'Date', 'datepicker']"></custom_elem>
```

Notice that first element in the object is the `label name`, followed by `input field type`.

So the generated html from the component would be:

```
First Name: <input type="text" />
Date: <input type="date" />
```

Using this parameters I want to generate html code in my component.

Q1. Is this possible?
Q2. If yes to above, then how? [Please explain since today's my first day of experiencing angular, I have no background working with this]

#### Note: I also came across angular elements, and I don't want to use it because i read that it is not fully supported by browsers yet. Hence I won't be able to get it approved at my organisation.

Let me know in comments, if any further details are required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should consider using an array of objects, if you decide to go this route. E.g., `[parameters]="[{'label':'First Name','type':'textbox'},{'label':'Date','type':'datepicker'}]"` That would make it more obvious how to use the input.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: +1 for @yurzui. If you start with Angular, consider reading the whole documentation. I know it's long and exhausting, but if you start, it's totally worth it (besides, every basic question that you will ask will make people redirect you to the documentation, so save yourself some time !)

Comment: The tutorial and documentation are really helpful.
https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes that would be a great idea, but the current problem i am facing is figuring out how to generate html tags based on this user input.

Comment: There is more than one way to do it. One way is to write the template with a loop that goes over the parameters and generates the tags according to the values.

Comment: @csfragstaa you're asking the wrong question. in angular you don't, directly, manipulate the DOM, this isn't JQUERY, you work with objects and let angular do the heavy lifting for you

Comment: @Stavm I apologise, but as I said It's my first day getting to know angular, so I just want to figure out, how I can achieve my requirement.

Comment: @Oram, where would i place my loop? in the `export class SubscriberComponent {
}`? Can you share a demo in answer, it will be very helpful.

Comment: In the example ishani shah posted there is an example of a for loop.
`<div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">`

Comment: I didn't get that example properly...

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link this gives you dynamic form with different control type
you need to just pass QuestionBase class as parameter
**[Angular Reusable Component with Dynamic form](https://stackblitz.com/angular/brljyjexkdld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form-question.component.ts)**

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, so if I have 25 search screens here, then for each screen I'll have to define a new `question.service.ts`? 


Edit: I basically can't understand `<app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>`, where the "question" data is coming from? [question] => object, "question" => ? Please help me understand.

Comment: Questions is coming from the **app.component.ts** which is calling the *question.service.ts**. It is essentially an array of objects, which is denoted by the `any[]`. The program is passing an object from the **app.component** (gets data) -> **dynamic-form.component** (transforms it into a form) -> **dynamic-form-question** (where it is used).

Comment: Okie..understood, but this approach doesn't seems good, For each screen, I'll have to write a service that retrieves html component. What I am looking for is to simply iterate over user's input parameters and generate html by looping those parameters in my component. Please suggest.

Comment: @csfragstaa maybe instead of jumping into forms right away, try dynamically loading html with a `*ngFor` loop, then start passing arguments into the child, then start playing with passing in a form. You keep saying this is your first day and forms aren't a first day subject.